# How to use linq to group a list of strings on only certain strings

Tags: c#, string, linq, grouping

example list of strings:

```cs
var test = new List<string>{
    "hdr1","abc","def","ghi","hdr2","lmn","opq","hdr3","rst","xyz"
};
```

I want to partition this list by `"hdr*"` so that each group contains elements...

```
"hdr1","abc","def","ghi"  
"hdr2","lmn","opq",  
"hdr3","rst","xyz"
```

I tried:

```cs
var result = test.GroupBy(g => g.StartsWith("hdr"));
```

but this gives me two groups

```
"hdr1","hdr2","hdr3"  
"abc","def"..."xyz"
```

What is the proper LINQ statement I should use? Let me emphasize that the strings following `"hdr*"` could be anything. The only thing they have in common is that they follow `"hdr*"`.

Comment: Why does it have to be LINQ, rather than a foreach or a while loop?

Comment: It doesn't have to be Linq and of course there are many ways to partition this otherwise. I'm just curious how you would do this using Linq, but perhaps this scenario is not appropriate for Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two groups because one group is the group of elements starting with `"hdr"` and the other group is the group of elements not starting with `"hdr"`. `StartsWith` returns a `bool`, so this results in two groups having the Keys `false` and `true`.

You can use statement blocks in LINQ. This enables us to do:

```cs
string header = null;
var groups = test
    .Select(s => {
        if (s.StartsWith("hdr")) header = s;
        return s;
    })
    .Where(s => header != s)
    .GroupBy(s => header);
```

We store the last header in `header`. The where clause eliminates the header itself, since the header is the group key.

The following test...

```cs
foreach (var g in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
    foreach (var item in g) {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + item);
    }
}
```

... prints this with the given list:

```
hdr1
    abc
    def
    ghi
hdr2
    lmn
    opq
hdr3
    rst
    xyz
```

Instead, we can also create lists with the header as first element:

```cs
string header = null;
IEnumerable<List<string>> lists = test
    .Select(s => {
        if (s.StartsWith("hdr")) {
            header = s;
        }
        return s;
    })
    .GroupBy(s => header)
    .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

This test...

```cs
foreach (var l in lists) {
    foreach (var item in l) {
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

... prints:

```
hdr1 abc def ghi
hdr2 lmn opq
hdr3 rst xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a fancy [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) `GroupWhen` that starts a new group when it finds a matching item. Just like [`IEnumerable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))) it will return a "list" of groups:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupWhen<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var i = 0;
    // This method "marks" which group each item belongs in
    // by creating a Tuple with the item and group number
    IEnumerable<(T Item, int GroupNum)> Iterate()
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (predicate(item)) i++; // Start new group
            yield return (item, i);
        }
    }
    // Group items by the "mark" from above and only
    // output the Item from the Tuple, since the
    // GroupNum will be the 'int' key of the group
    return Iterate().GroupBy(tup => tup.GroupNum, tup => tup.Item);
}

// Use like so:
var list = new List<string> {"hdr1","abc","def","ghi","hdr2","lmn","opq","hdr3","rst","xyz"};
var groups = list.GroupWhen(s => s.StartsWith("hdr"))
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", groups.First()))
// hdr1,abc,def,ghi
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L4Pnit) for a test run.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your solutions. I learned a lot.

Comment: @oden That sounds good :) Remember to accept one of the answers if you think your problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying proper etiquette to this newbie. All 3 answers were great and I wish I could somehow select them all as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with LINQ expressions. But I don't think it's is much readable than a foreach loop.

```
var test = new List<string>{
    "hdr1","abc","def","ghi","hdr2","lmn","opq","hdr3","rst","xyz"
};

int groupid = 0;

var result = test.GroupBy(t =>
{
    if (t.StartsWith("hdr")) ++groupid;
    return groupid;
}).ToList();

result.Select(t => string.Join(' ', t)).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

/*
 Outputs:
hdr1 abc def ghi
hdr2 lmn opq
hdr3 rst xyz
 */
```